# Create SFTP user programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sftp

I have been using windows server 2012 R2 and I have bitvise SSH for SFTP and I want to create SFTP user programmatically in my application.

What I am thinking to do is When any user signup into the application then application will create a new folder and SFTP credentials for a newly created folder.So each user can access their SFTP credentials for uploading their files in their associated folder.

I can find the solution to create FTP users dynamically but I want to create SFTP user.

**Question:** Is it possible to create SFTP user using c#? If it is then how?

Comment: https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-guide-scriptable says "Bitvise SSH Server comes with a textual configuration utility, BssCfg, which is useful for administering SSH servers in large-scale installations. It also comes with a configuration COM object, BssCfgManip, which can be used to configure the SSH Server from any language that supports COM, but is especially intended for use with PowerShell." You should be able to use a COM object from C#. Note that SSH/SFTP users are really Windows users of the machine, with certain privileges which Bitvise can help control.

Answer (score 1):

You can create SFPT user using C# like :

```
var cfg = new CBssCfg726("BssCfg726.BssCfg726");

cfg.SetSite("Bitvise SSH Server");

cfg.LoadServerSettings();


cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.virtAccount ="Virtual Account Name";
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.virtPassword.Set("Password");
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.group = "Virtual Users";

//if already virtAccountsEx then first delete... 
for (uint i = 0; i < cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.count; i++) {
    if (cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.GetItem(i).virtAccount == "Virtual Account Name") {
        cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.Erase(i);
    }
}
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.fwding.srvSideC2S.ipv4Ex.@new.targetHost = "127.0.0.1";
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.fwding.srvSideC2S.ipv4Ex.@new.targetPort = 80;
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.fwding.srvSideC2S.ipv4Ex.@new.proxyProfile = "Default";
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.loginAllowed = cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes;
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.Clear();
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.@new.sfsMountPath = "/";
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.@new.realRootPath = "Path to folder";
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.NewCommit();
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.fwding.srvSideC2S.ipv4Ex.NewCommit();
cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.NewCommit();
cfg.SaveServerSettings();
```